# NRF Connect in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

we are developing an app that have an ability to connect with a watch, the app can send & receive command from the app.

when I use nrf connect app to send command the watch take the command and we can see result.

when I implemented the connection & sending command from our app it successfully shows command send but no result on watch like set the time for example

I already trued to used this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus & https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble

but same result ! I can send a command with no result on watch! when use the nrf connect app to test everything is working even Im use same serviceID & charasterricID.

can any one help ?

we are developing an app that have an ability to connect with a watch, the app can send & receive command from the app.